# r- Adding multiple unrelated nonlinear fuctions (not fitted) to a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, nonlinear-functions, quantile

I have made a scatter plot of raw data. The equation for the quantile lines takes the form of y=10^a*x^b. (The equation for the quantile was log transformed and meaningless to the audience when viewed). How do I add this form of a function to the scatter plot of the raw data. 
I think this may be a matter of my not knowing the terminology to search for the right method.

Comment: Are a and b known constants?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=1
b=2

curve(10^a*x^b,add =T,from=0,to=10)
```